# Initialize a vector properly

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
struct the_raw_data {
    double data;
    double other;
};

int testingReadFunctionsout() {
    std::vector<the_raw_data> &thevector;  /*Here is where the initialization needs to happen*/ 
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<the_raw_data>& readDataFromFileOut(std::__cxx11::string)’:
main.cpp:108:29: error: ‘v’ declared as reference but not initialized
  std::vector<the_raw_data>& v;
```

Comment: It all went over my head, I was returning it from a different function and forgot to change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The error is self-explanatory:

> **‘v’ declared as reference but not initialized**

You have declared a variable `v` that is a **reference**, but it does not reference anything:

```
std::vector<the_raw_data> &thevector; // what is thevector pointing at? NOTHING!
```

You can't have uninitialized references in C++.  A reference is just an alias for another object, so you have to initialize it to point at something (in practical terms, think of a reference as being like a pointer that can never be NULL, because that is how most compilers actually implement it), eg:

```
std::vector<the_raw_data> &thevector = SomeOtherObject;
```

Where `SomeOtherObject` is another `std::vector<the_raw_data>` object elsewhere in memory.

If you want `v` to be an actual `std::vector<the_raw_data>` object of its own, just get rid of the `&` in the variable declaration:

```
std::vector<the_raw_data> thevector;
```